# itext - filled form field should show text from beginning when not full text can be shown

Tags: java, itext

I'm using `iText 2.1.7`(I know, it's old, but it's the last LGPL version and I have no influence over it) and am filling out a PDF form with `PdfStamper` and `AcroFields` . Generally, it all works fine except for one use case: when the text to insert into a field is wider than the field, the text is centered in the field. For example (pipe characters depict the field):

`Test test |äÄüÜö|Öß ąćęłńóśżź`

i.e. the visible part is `äÄüÜö`.
I'm Ok with the truncating, but is there a way of telling the field to always show the text from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a TextField, there is a setAlignemnt() call using constants from Element to specify the alignment.  I don't have iText handy any more, so I can't tell you what the name is.

If it's a PdfFormField, things look to be much more complicated, and I haven't found a reference to the right method yet.  I expect there is something there for alignment, maybe even setAlignment(), but again I don't have the stuff in front of me any more to look it up.

Another possibility, if PdfFormField doesn't have it, is PdfAppearance -- it apperas to have lots of low-level stuff (fill stroke, rectangle, setColorFill, setLineWidth) and might have an alignment as well.

Good luck.

Comment: I don't have a TextField or any other subclass of Element. I just have AcroFields, with methods such as getField (returns the value), setField (set the value) etc. There seems to be no obvious way of changing the alignment.

Comment: Are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301578/align-acrofields-in-java or http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Need-help-right-justifying-AcroFields-td2141572.html any help?

Comment: thanks, that was the solution.

Comment: some people upvote answers, or even mark the question as 'answered'...

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. I did upvote the answer you linked to, but it is different from your answer here - your answer here doesn't really answer my question. I did upvote your comment, though, as it leads to the solution. What else do you expect me to do?